# Why regular expression ((x,y)|(x,z)) is nondeterministic?

Tags: java, regex

Why regular expression ((x,y)|(x,z)) is nondeterministic as the book "Core Java" said? The author gives his point:

> When the parser sees x, it doesn’t know which of the two alternatives to take.This expression can be rewritten in a deterministic form as (x,(y|z))

Could anyone can give me an explanation?

Comment: The explanation quoted seems pretty clear to me. In the first case, encountering `x` leaves us with two possible alternatives, in the second case that doesn't happen.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To have a deterministic form, you are only allowed to have a maximum of one possible way at your current position.  Let's say you have a string "**x,y**". Now the regex engine looks at the first character, the "**x**". In your expression you have 2 possibilities how your string can go on after an "**x**" at the first position to accept your input.  Next there are 2 ways to check.  Either if the string is followed by "**,y**" or by "**,z**".

```
   , ⇨ y
 ⬀
x
 ⬂
   , ⇨ z
```

For (x,(y|z)) you always have just one way.  If an "**x**" is on position 1 you go to position 2.  Same there, just with the "**,**".  Finally he has to check if there is a "**y**" or a "**z**" on position 3 to accept the word.  There were never 2 ways.

```
x ⇨ , ⇨ (y or z)
```

Answer (score 3):

A finite state machine is called a nondeterministic finite automaton (NFA), if
given a specific state, it can have multiple transitions with the same symbol

That means your grammar (i.e. your regex) can lead to have 2 derivation trees for the same expression and we don't know the state that the automaton is going to choose :

```
       x 
      / \
     /   \
    /     \
   ,       ,
   |       |
   |       | 
   y       z
```

Answer (score 1):

> ((x,y)|(x,z))

In this case, when parser sees `x`, it does not know which group to take i.e `x,y` or `x,z` (non deterministic form)

> (x,(y|z))

In this case, parser can read `x,` and now free to choose `y` or `z` (deterministic form)

Answer (score 1):

I think the mentioned issue only is relevant when group matching is involved.

If x is `([a-z][a-z])` and y is `([0-6][0-6])` and z is `([3-9][3-9])` then you have a regular expression like this:

```
((([a-z][a-z]),([0-6][0-6]))|(([a-z][a-z]),([3-9][3-9])))
```

Given an input like `pq,45` this can be matched taking either side of the pipe symbol (i. e. it matches both `(([a-z][a-z]),([0-6][0-6]))` *and* `(([a-z][a-z]),([3-9][3-9]))`).

In such a case the standard defines that the left side of the pipe symbol has preference before the right side.  The value for x can be found in group number 3 then (the third opening parenthesis).

If the input now changes to be e. g. `pq,78`, then the match for x hasn't changed at all (it is still `pq`) but now the right side of the pipe symbol matches and you will find x's value in group number 6.

This can be avoided by using a more stable regular expression like `(([a-z][a-z]),(([0-6][0-6])|([3-9][3-9])))` in which x always will be in group 2.